# Implement Multithreading in JDBC

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

Might be my question is very silly but I have to clear this, I have a Java class in that I am fetching data from 2 different `mysql` tables (Using JDBC)
**My Code:**

```
pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(Quert1);
pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(Query2);

rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();
rs2 = pstmtCount.executeQuery();
```

I execute query one by one and get 2 `ResultSet` I want to know should I need to Implement `threading` here so the One `thread` execute `Query1` and other `Query1`

Comment: It depends how slow the queries are. You need to profile using both approaches and then make a decision if code complexity using multiple threads is worth the performance gain.

Comment: If you are going to use separate threads, then make sure you use separate connections per thread. Although theoretically JDBC driver should be thread-safe, it is better not to use a single connection concurrently.

Comment: The network isn't multi-threaded. This is unlikely to be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but then you need one JDBC connection per thread, as they are (officially) not thread-safe. This problem is however already solved by most server implementations, i.E. Tomcat has a JDBC pool for that.

If you should do that completely depends on the time it takes to execute those queries, and whether or not performance is relevant in this case. If there is no reason to speed things up, then it is usually better to use the simplest solution over the fastest. Also keep in mind that threading itself costs time, too, and if your query finishes faster than the time it would take to start and close a new thread, then threading will actually make it slower.

If your code runs in a server environment there is another problem: the server has a limited amount of cores, and depending on the load secondary threads cannot be executed simply because there is no free core available. In this environment a threading solution would appear to speed things up during testing, but as soon as the system is put under load the speed advantage is gone.